# Field in tablix (Report Viewer)

Tags: wpf, reportviewer, ssrs-tablix

How can I change a numeric field in tablix to a string message when that field is not numeric?
For example I am using the expression:
=IIf(IsNumeric(Fields!ResultadoString1.Value),Format(Min(Cdbl(Fields!ResultadoString1.Value)),"N4"), Nothing) and it's showing #Error
Could you help me?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you display the field value without the above formula? As in what is the display if your input is just:  "=Fields!ResultadoString1.Value"

Comment: Yes, if I put a direct value it works perfectly.

Comment: I think 'Nothing' might be causing the error. Seems like the value isn't numeric. I don't think 'Nothing' is a reserved key word or function. Maybe you want to ouptut Nothing as a message? If so just enclose it: "Nothing".

Comment: I did that but I got the same error.

Comment: What is the output if you put "=IsNumeric(Fields!ResultadoString1.Value)"

Comment: The output is False

Comment: No make sense, but the problem is in Cdbl . If I change to Val it works more or less because the numbers after decimal point is not included. For example: 123.45 shows me 123.00 =IIf(IsNumeric(Fields!ResultadoString2.Value),Format(Max(Val(Fields!ResultadoString2.Value.ToString)),"N4")," ")

Comment: Anyway why shows me an error if the condition is false. No make sense it!

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Comment: Not yet. I can not find the error.

Comment: Maybe you would want to refactor your question a bit..State what you have tried & done and post some results of your debugging.

Comment: I have a column that can be a numeric value or a string. If it is numeric, it works perfectly but if it is a string give me an error. I fill many rows with that values numeric or not. So, in the last row I put a field to show the minimum value. I need an expression that satisfy both situations. It is important to say that when I have a string value, I want it shows me a blank space.

Comment: Hmm, based on your new findings can you refactor your question? That it may be more useful for anyone who might encounter the same thing.

Comment: =IIf(IsNumeric(yourField), Format(yourField), String.Empty) should work. Unless your problem fields are some sort of numeric.

Comment: also, can you share what is the data type from your datatable or tableadapter.

Comment: It follows my solution: =IIf(IsNumeric(Fields!ResultadoString1.Value),Format(Min(CDbl(IIf(IsNumeric(Fields!ResultadoString1.Value), Fields!ResultadoString1.Value, 0))),"N4"), String.Empty)